# Docker info not matching settings in Docker GUI on mac

Tags: docker

I installed Docker (version 18.06.1-ce-mac73) on a MacBook Pro with macOS High Sierra (version 10.13.6). When I go to Preferences -> Advanced in Docker GUI, I see that memory limit is set to 4GB and CPUs are set to 2. However, running docker info from the terminal shows that total memory is 995.6MiB and CPUs is 1.

[image: docker info snippet]

It seems that the 995.6MiB limit is enforced, because I'm trying to build a project inside a container and by checking docker stats I see that it runs out of memory when 995.6MiB limit is reached.

Shouldn't docker info match the GUI configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `docker` command is pointed at a VirtualBox VM, probably one installed via Docker Machine or Docker Toolbox.  The Docker for Mac "whale" app uses a different virtualization system.  (Check: if you `echo $DOCKER_HOST`, does it say something like `tcp://192.168.99.100:2376`?)

You can "deactivate" the Docker VM in your shell by running

```
eval $(docker-machine env -u)
docker info
```

and having done that can `docker-machine rm` the VM.

Comment: Agree, you can find more advice here https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem, indeed. I followed the instructions in the link provided by @Mark and fixed it. Marking the answer as correct.